# Smart Map Lat+Lng is present but no pin on map

Tags: plugin-smartmap

My map isn't showing all of the markers that it should. I am querying a user group to return the locations as follows:

```
{% set locations = craft.users.group('fullMembership') %} {{ craft.smartMap.map(locations, options) }}
```

FYI There are around 400 users in this group and only a small amount of them have logged in and set their Map Pin.

Each user in this group has a profile page; Those user who have located their address  all show their map pin on their profile. However the members Directory index map is incomplete, some pins are missing.

Comment: It seems that any new users that I update with their lat / lng aren't added to the directory map.

Answer (score 2):

As Craft defaults to only returning 100 elements, setting the `limit(null)` parameter to the query fixed this issue.

```
{% set locations = craft.users.group('fullMembership').limit(null) %}
```